# Leaflet Opacity using geoJSON data

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using the Leaflet library to add geoJSON data to my map in a React functional component.  I have simple code per the samples shown at https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/.

Here is my code:

```
const someOptions = {
  fillColor: "yellow",
  fillOpacity: 0.25,
  opacity: 0.65,
  color: "black",
  weight: 1,
};

L.geoJSON(mapData, {
  style: someOptions,
}).addTo(map);
```

"mapData" is a json file (not geoJSON because React complains about it) that contains properly formatted json data.  This is a sample of one of the records in the "mapData" json file:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "NRN": "ICAOXCATSP",
    "SERIES": "ICAO",
    // ...
    "ED_DATE": "06/01/2016"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [180.000000000100044, 90.000000000099988],
          [180.000000000100044, -89.999999999900012],
          [-179.999999999900041, -89.999999999900012],
          [-179.999999999900041, 90.000000000099988],
          [180.000000000100044, 90.000000000099988]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

When I load this json file the image shows correctly EXCEPT the opacity parameters are not taking affect.  I end up with giant yellow area on my map that is not translucent at all.  Its as if the `fillOpacity` value is 1.

On other geoJSON files I have used the results I get is that some of the shapes put on the map are translucent while others are not.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

since you have an static option you dont need to delcare the style like this

```
L.geoJSON(mapData, {
  style: someOptions,
}).addTo(map);
```

it needs to be like this

```
 L.geoJSON(mapData, someOptions).addTo(map)
```

or

```
 L.geoJSON(mapData, {
   fillColor: "yellow",
   fillOpacity: 0.25,
   opacity: 0.65,
   color: "black",
   weight: 1,
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to me with not react but Vue.

It seemed a loading order problem.

It's not fundamental solution but reloading style worked for me.

```
const geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(mapData, {
  style: someOptions,
});

geoJsonLayer.addTo(map);

setTimeout(function () {
  geoJsonLayer.setStyle(someOptions);
},10);
```